# CSS3: Shadow only without parent background

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with CSS3 Shadows that I did not expirience before.
It seems like a box-shadow, that is applied to a div via the :before and :after selector, is only possible, if the container of the div has no background-color set.

Is there any way to make this possible?

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="shadow-box">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

The `.container` must not have a background-color set. I created an example on http://jsfiddle.net/v1utr15n/

Comment: Why don't put the code of the box-shadow inside shadow-box?

Comment: I think it has to do with `z-index` properties not being setup correctly. The shadow is rendered below the `.container`. When you set a `background-color` on the `.container` it will be opaque and thus covering the shadow. Btw adding a `opacity: 0.99` to the `.container` seems to solve it. That might guide you to understand what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `.container` will start a new stacking order. You can do this by either setting a `position: relative; z-index: 0` or a opacity other than 1, e.g. `opacity: .9999`.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.shadow-box {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.shadow-box:before,
.shadow-box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px / 10px;
  border-radius: 100px / 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="shadow-box">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

See http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/ for some background information on z-index and stacking order context.

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, thanks for the interesting background information!

Answer (score 0):

Put the code of the box-shadow in the shadow-box class, not in before or after.

URL: http://jsfiddle.net/v1utr15n/1/

```css
.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 500px;
}
.shadow-box {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.shadow-box:before,
.shadow-box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px / 10px;
  border-radius: 100px / 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="shadow-box">
    Shadow box
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will of course work, but will make a completely different shadow, which is not my intention. Try it out by removing the background-color of the .container in my fiddle

Comment: ¡Ah! I understand you now. I'm thinking... (Thanks for you correction CKUjjer)

Comment: Not sure I understand, but did you try for .container : background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0); ?

Comment: I think this works: I'm waiting for what tell Schlimpf. I add your code in http://jsfiddle.net/v1utr15n/2/

Comment: @Bonatoc that doesn't do the trick, try giving the `.container` a pink background color like `rgba(255, 153, 153, 1)` to see why.

Comment: So the .container may have a background-color, but you assume that since .shadow-box is above in the DOM hierarchy, it should appear on a higher z-index than .container, am I right?

Comment: Yes... you're right. I don't know how help you Schlimpf. I retire. I wish you find the solution.

Comment: @schlimpf. My guess is that you need a 3rd div... a position:relative that encapsulates .container and .shadow-box, both with absolute positions. But this may be, of course, not what you want. Even if you play with z-index, the fact that .shadow-box is encapsulated in .container, makes it worthless IMO.